# Which apache rewrite rule will be faster? Subrequest or many exceptions?

Tags: apache

Which Rewrite Rule will be faster?

First with many exceptions:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/index.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/kernel/.+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/resource/.+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Or Second with subrequest:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/index.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F`

Comment: You could turn on RewriteLog and see what/how many steps are performed in each case (for different test URLs). But I doubt that there will be a real difference that is noticeable or even relevant.

Comment: How I can turn on this logging?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: First run writes more logs.

Comment: But as I said, I doubt this has much informative value …

Comment: okay, I did run Apache Benchmark (10000 request with 10 clients) and get 38.16 [#/sec] for first vanriant, 54.32 [#/sec] for second.